# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in comma seperated numbers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var batchidstring = <?php echo $batchId; ?>;
</script>
```

`$batchId` value is `1,2,3,4,5`

They were seperated with comma.

I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

The error where in code  **var batchidstring = 1,2,3,4,5;**

Can anyone show me or correct the codes?

Comment: If it's supposed to be a string, it should be in quotes.

Comment: `var batchidstring = '<?php echo $batchId; ?>';` or `var batchidstring = <?php echo json_encode($batchId); ?>;`

Comment: Also if the numbers are separated by *commas* why are you splitting on "."?

Comment: Note that if you surrounded the list of numbers with `[ ]` characters instead of quotes you'd get a proper array of numbers without the need to `.split()`.

Comment: sorry i it was by mistake by typping

Comment: Thanks it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need  string you must wrap the var  with proper quote

```
var batchidstring = <?php echo "'" . $batchId . "'"; ?>;
```